# How to fetch RSpec test name in before(:each) block without a spec_helper

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, hook

So here's an example basic test suite:

```
describe "Main test suite" do
  it "should run test #1" do
    ...
  end
  it "should run test #2" do
    ...
  end
end
```

I want to add a `before(:each)` which does some special logic with the full test name (it'll be inserting the test name as a metadata header into all of the HTTP requests made by each test).  I've found that using `"#{self.class.description}"` only captures the test suite name ("Main test suite" in this case), but I also need to capture the test name itself.

I've seen some other similar questions on StackOverflow such as [Getting the full RSpec test name from within a before(:each) block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816322/getting-the-full-rspec-test-name-from-within-a-beforeeach-block), but the answers all involve adding `Spec::Runner.configure` or `RSpec.configure` options to the `spec_helper.rb`, but we're running these tests through a custom environment which doesn't use a `spec_helper.rb`, so I need a solution that doesn't depend on that.

I've also seen other examples such as [How to get current context name of rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518264/how-to-get-current-context-name-of-rspec) where they are doing the logging in the test itself instead of in a `before(:each)` block, so they can just do something like: `it "should Bar" do |example| puts "#{self.class.description} #{example.description}" end`.  But we have hundreds of these tests and I don't want to copy-paste the same logic in every test -- this seems like an ideal use case for a `before(:each)` block.

Comment: You don't need to use spec_helper, you just need the `Spec::Runner.configure do |config|` block. What's wrong with including that in your spec file?

Comment: I tried it, it didn't do anything... Does it matter where I put it?  I tried putting it in the constructor and in the `before(:all)` block, but neither seems to have any effect even when I put print statements in there they never got run.

Comment: Put it (or whatever version of that code is right for your version of rspec) as the first lines of your spec, BEFORE any other lines, the same way it would be as if you had used `require ‘spec_helper’`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```rb
describe "Main test suite" do
  before(:each) do |x|
    puts "#{x.class.description} - #{x.example.description}"
  end

  it "should run test #1" do
    ...
  end
  it "should run test #2" do
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: just check the Rpsec doc, https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/metadata/current-example
I wonder if you have other wrapper which wraps the example object?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by putting this at the top of my file:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.before(:each) do |x|
        do_stuff("#{x.class.description} - #{x.example.description}")
    end
end
```